# ¿Como cambiar el metodo de encriptacion que utiliza xenforo por defecto?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, encriptación, bcryptjs

**He estado realizando configuraciones en el archivo password hash de xenforo, que supuestamente es el archivo relacionado con el cifrado y verificacion de contraseñas, mi objetivo es cambiar el metodo de cifrado que utiliza xenforo por defecto que en este caso es (BCRYPT), pero la verdad no se donde se realizan estas configuraciones si en las carpetas de autenticacion o en las carpetas de registro. Si tienen alguna idea se los agradeceria mucho.**